# d3 "hidden" attribute bug or bug in my code?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've built a webpage that flips between two photos of the Crab Nebula taken in 1956 and 1999. The page works as I expect in Chrome and Firefox but not IE10. I'm not sure that the problem is in IE10 and not my code as I had to hack my code to get it to work in Chrome and Firefox.

Here's the javascript snippet that's failing in IE10 and sort of works in Chrome and Firefox:

```
if(curHelp=="Show Text"){
    curHelp = "Hide Text";
    d3s=d3.selectAll("p");
    d3s.attr("hidden",false);
    d3s[0][0].hidden=false; // d3s.attr("hidden",false) doesn't work.
    d3s[0][1].hidden=false; // It sets  all "hidden" attribute for paragraphs to true.
    d3s[0][2].hidden=false; // I hacked in these 4 lines just to get the page to work.
    d3s[0][3].hidden=false; 
}else{
    curHelp = "Show Text";
    d3s=d3.selectAll("p");
    d3s.attr("hidden",true);  // this works but maybe because it's a bug?
}
```

The line "d3s.attr("hidden",false) sets all the paragraphs hidden attribute to true.

I think the bug's in my code but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong because the .attr function call works as intended when I intend to hide the paragraphs but fails when I intend to display them.

Here's a link to the [page](http://greenes.com/Supernovas.html) I'm working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
d3.selectAll("p").style("display", "none")
```

[Visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/visibility) is a CSS property; [.style](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-style) should be used to set it instead of .attr

Comment: So why does it work as intended when "hidden" is set to true?

Comment: I don't begin to understand why the .attr call worked when I was setting "hidden" to true but failed when I used .attr to set it to false. However, d3.selectAll("p").style("display", "block") had the desired effect. Thanks.